# I want to save uuid on backend with image name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to save uuid on backend with image name I already save Image name on backend by clicking the button ( HandleCreate ) you show I my code :

```
const HandleCreate = async (e) => {


e.preventDefault();


obj['urlToImage'] = image.name;
 const res = await axios.post('API',obj )

};
```

and this is my input code:

```
 <input
            type="file"
            style={{ opacity: "0%" }}
            htmlFor="fileInput"
            id="urlToImage"
            name="myImage"

            onChange={(e)=>( handleInput(e))}
             accept="image/*"
            
          />
```

and the handleInput you show in onChange function in define below :

```
 const handleInput = (e) => {
console.log(e);
let name = e.target.id;
obj[name] = e.target.value;
console.log(obj[name]);

 };
```

this is total code now I dont understand where i put this uuid so when I save image id will also save with name tis is uuid code :

```
const unique_id = uuid();
```

I hope some one show me sample

Comment: You need to POST the file to the server. https://nextjs.org/blog/forms

Comment: I post file name to server but don't know how to post uuid with file

Comment: The server is where you want to create and set the UUID. You may have id tampering in the frontend that breaks your application.

Comment: any sample please